# Zoom image in raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael

I have a problem.
I create zooming image in canvas, but i can't transfer this in raphaeljs
How make zooming in cursor coordinats?

Raphaeljs:
http://jsfiddle.net/qCzqF/2/

```
function zoomTo (x,y,z) {

c.translate(
    originx,
    originy
);
c.scale(z,z);
c.translate(
    -( x / scale + originx - x / ( scale * z ) ),
    -( y / scale + originy - y / ( scale * z ) )
);

originx = ( x / scale + originx - x / ( scale * z ) );
originy = ( y / scale + originy - y / ( scale * z ) );
scale *= z;
```

Canvas:
http://jsfiddle.net/JtctY/

```
function zoomTo (x,y,z) {

context.translate(
    originx,
    originy
);
context.scale(z,z);
context.translate(
    -( x / scale + originx - x / ( scale * z ) ),
    -( y / scale + originy - y / ( scale * z ) )
);

originx = ( x / scale + originx - x / ( scale * z ) );
originy = ( y / scale + originy - y / ( scale * z ) );
scale *= z;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your zooming function seems fine to me, you just aren't feeding it the correct x/y position of the mouse. You want to use the mouse position relative to the svg container

```
var mousex = event.clientX - paper.clientX;
var mousey = event.clientY - paper.clientY;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mFaD2/